# Change in SVG Text

Tags: html, css, svg

I need help in changing the text from `Real Pirates Have Anchors` to `Ripple Effect Button`.

My code:

```
<svg id="pirates" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="385.5" height="200.39" viewBox="0 0 385.5 200.39">
  <title>Animated Text</title>
  <path id="r-real" class="letter" d="M330.55,528.42c-1.2.1-1.2,3.1-.3,3.9,2.3,2,3.5.7,3.5,3.5,0,5.9-5.4,8.7-10.7,7.6-15.5-3.2-16.5-38.4-28.9-45.9,16.6-3.3,17.1-39.21,3.6-41.81a123.52,123.52,0,0,0-17.7-.5,1.76,1.76,0,0,0-1,1.7c.2,3.8,2.8,1.7,3.7,4.4.4,1.6,1.3,59.91-1.1,66.71-.9,2.7-3.5.6-3.9,4.4,0,.6.3,1.6,1,1.7s11,.5,13,.6c.7,0,.9-1.1.9-1.2-.2-3.8-2-3.9-3.2-4.4-1.5-.6-1.7-2.1-1.7-4.3.1-9.7.1-16.6.2-26.5,0-1.5,3.9,2.6,4.4,3.1,11.3,12.8,10.8,45.8,31.4,47.6,7.9.7,15.2-4.3,15.2-14.1,0-1.8.3-1.3,2.6-3.2a5,5,0,0,0,.9-3.3C342.05,527.22,333.75,527.92,330.55,528.42Zm-42.4-36.2c.1-8.5.2-19.31.5-27.71.2-5,3-5,7.4-4.6C306.15,460.81,305.15,497.32,288.15,492.22Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="e-real" class="letter" d="M346.45,471.31c0,.6-1.1.8-1.2.8-4.8-.2-2.5-2.6-4.4-3.8s-11.2-1.7-13.9.4c-1.1.8-1,2.2-1,3.8-.2,9-.2,7.6-.3,16.81,0,2,7.1,1.2,8.6.4,1.7-.8.3-2.7,3.8-2.8.5-.1,1.5.3,1.6.8.2.7-.4,9.3-.3,11,.1.6-1.1.7-1.2.7-4.7-.4-2.5-2.5-4.1-3.6-1-.7-8.4-2.3-8.5.2,0,1.2-1.2,17.9.7,19.4,2.6,2.1,12.1,2.1,14.1.9s-.3-3.6,4.4-3.8c.2,0,1.3.2,1.2.8-.1,1.2.8,5.2-.1,8.2-.1.5-26.1.1-29.6-.6-.6-.2-.9-1.1-.9-1.7.4-3.8,3.2-1.7,3.9-4.4,1.5-5.7,1.9-41.51.6-45.51-.8-2.7-3.4-.6-3.7-4.4-.1-.6.3-1.5.9-1.6,3.5-.8,29.3-.9,29.4-.4C347.25,466,346.35,470.11,346.45,471.31Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="a-real" class="letter" d="M373.25,535.12c.3-2.5-1.4-16.8-2.5-24.7-4.8,0-6.8-.1-11.5-.1-1.6,7.7-3.1,14-3.2,16.6,0,1.9,3.7.1,3.8,5.2,0,.2-.2,1.3-.9,1.3-2-.1-12.2-.1-13-.3-.6-.1-1-1.1-.9-1.6.5-3.8,3.7-1.8,4.6-4.6,3-10,11.4-52.81,13.1-65.91.4-3.4-2.8-1.9-2.9-5.8,0-.1.2-1.2.9-1.2,2,.2,11.1-.3,12-.1a1.68,1.68,0,0,1,.9,1.7c-.5,3.8-3,1.6-3.1,4.4-.1,3.7,6.8,67.71,8.8,75.21.8,2.8,3.5.7,3.6,4.5a1.85,1.85,0,0,1-1.1,1.7c-.9.1-9.2.2-11.2.2-.3,0-.5-.4-.6-.7C368.85,537,373,538,373.25,535.12Zm-3.2-29.4c-1.6-12-1.8-25.41-3.7-36.31-2.8,11.51-4,24.11-6.5,36.11C364.05,505.52,366,505.72,370.05,505.72Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="l-real" class="letter" d="M413.15,532.42c.1,0,1.2.2,1.2.8-.1,1.2.8,5.2-.1,8.2-.1.5-22.9.1-26.3-.6a1.76,1.76,0,0,1-1-1.7c.4-3.8,3-1.7,3.9-4.4,2.4-6.8,1.6-79.91,1.2-81.41-.9-2.8-3.5-.7-3.7-4.5-.1-.5.3-1.5,1-1.6s11,.3,13,.2c.6,0,.8,1.1.7,1.2-.5,6.4-4.8.2-5.1,7.8-.2,6.1-2,69.51-.7,78.11.5,3.5,9.9,2.7,11.5,1.7C410.65,535,408.35,532.62,413.15,532.42Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="p-pirates" class="letter" d="M444.05,506.22c-.1,9.9-.2,17.5-.2,27.3,0,2.1.2,3.7,1.6,4.2s3,.6,3.2,4.4c0,.1-.2,1.2-.8,1.2-2-.1-12.2-.4-13.1-.6-.6-.1-1-1.1-.9-1.6.4-3.8,2.9-1.7,3.9-4.5,2.3-6.8,1.5-70.41,1-72-.8-2.8-3.4-.7-3.7-4.5,0-.5.4-1.5,1-1.6,1.6-.4,14.2-.2,17.7.5,12.9,2.4,13.1,40-1.3,45.71-2.4,1-5.6,1-8.2,1.2C444.15,505.92,444.05,506,444.05,506.22Zm7.4-43c-4.3-.5-6.5-.5-6.7,4.5-.3,8.4-.4,23.91-.5,32.41C461.25,505.22,462.35,464.31,451.45,463.21Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="i-pirates" class="letter" d="M482.25,527.92c0,.1-.2,1.2-.8,1.2-2-.1-12.2-.4-13.1-.6-.6-.1-1-1.1-.9-1.7.4-3.8,2.9-1.7,3.9-4.4,2.3-6.8,1.5-51.91,1-53.51-.8-2.7-3.4-.6-3.7-4.4a1.94,1.94,0,0,1,1-1.7c.9-.2,11,.4,13,.3.7,0,.8,1.1.8,1.2-.6,6.3-4.8.2-5.1,7.8-.8,19.81-.8,27.21-.9,47.11,0,2.2.2,3.7,1.6,4.3S482.05,524.12,482.25,527.92Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="r-pirates" class="letter" d="M529.35,529.42c-1.2.1-1.2,3.1-.4,3.9,2.4,2,3.6.7,3.5,3.5,0,5.8-2.8,9.9-6.4,9.9-13.9,0-9.4-40.4-24.2-49.2,16.7-3.3,17.2-39.21,3.6-41.71-3.5-.7-16.1-.9-17.7-.6a1.94,1.94,0,0,0-1,1.7c.3,3.8,2.9,1.7,3.7,4.4.5,1.6,1.3,59.91-1,66.71-1,2.7-3.5.6-3.9,4.5-.1.5.3,1.5.9,1.6.9.2,11.1.5,13.1.6.6,0,.8-1.1.8-1.2-.2-3.8-1.9-3.9-3.2-4.4s-1.6-2.1-1.6-4.3c0-9.7.1-16.6.2-26.5,0-1.5,3.9,2.5,4.4,3.1,10.3,13,7.3,50.4,26.3,50.2,6.7,0,11.3-7,11.3-15.7,0-1.8.2-1.3,2.5-3.2.7-.5,1.1-2.7,1-3.3C540.85,528.22,532.45,528.92,529.35,529.42ZM496,492.22c.1-8.5.2-19.31.5-27.71.2-5,3-5,7.3-4.6C513.85,460.81,513,497.42,496,492.22Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="a-pirates" class="letter" d="M555.65,545.32c-2.1-7.5-10.4-84.21-10.2-87.81.1-2.9,2.5-.6,3-4.5.1-.5-.2-1.5-.8-1.6-.9-.2-10.1.2-12.1.1-.6,0-.9,1.1-.9,1.2.1,3.9,3.4,2.4,2.9,5.7-1.7,13.1-8.4,48.81-11.4,58.91-.8,2.8-4,.7-4.5,4.5a1.61,1.61,0,0,0,.8,1.7c.9.1,11.1.2,13.1.2.6,0,.9-1.1.9-1.2-.1-5.1-3.9-3.4-3.8-5.2.1-2.7-.2-1.8,1.4-9.5,4.8-.1,6.8.1,11.5.1,1.1,7.9,4.2,34.8,4,37.3-.4,2.9-4.4,1.8-3.3,5.7.1.4.3.8.7.8,2-.1,10.3-.1,11.2-.3.6-.1,1-1.1,1-1.6C559.05,545.92,556.35,548,555.65,545.32Zm-21-42.3c2.5-12,3.7-24.6,6.5-36.21,1.9,11,2.1,24.41,3.8,36.31C540.75,503.22,538.85,503,534.65,503Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="t-pirates" class="letter" d="M593.75,440.91c.8,3.1-.1,7.2,0,8.5,0,.6-1.1.8-1.2.8-4.8-.2-2.5-2.7-4.3-3.8-2.4-1.4-8.8-1.3-10.9-.3-1.3.5-1,2.6-1,4.5-.4,20.8-.8,61.41-.6,74.51.1,7.6,4.5,1.4,4.9,7.8,0,.1-.2,1.2-.8,1.2-2-.1-12.1.4-13,.2-.6-.1-1-1-.9-1.6.3-3.8,2.9-1.7,3.7-4.4,2.4-7.5.6-80.91.6-80.91-1-3.2-10.2-1.7-11.3-1-1.8,1.1.4,3.6-4.4,3.8-.1,0-1.2-.2-1.1-.8.1-1.3-.9-5.4-.1-8.5C553.45,440.51,593.65,440.51,593.75,440.91Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="e-pirates" class="letter" d="M592.55,469.61c-.9-2.7-3.4-.6-3.8-4.4,0-.6.4-1.5,1-1.6,3.5-.8,29.3-.8,29.4-.4.8,3.1-.1,7.2,0,8.5,0,.5-1.1.7-1.2.7-4.8-.2-2.5-2.6-4.4-3.8s-11.3-1.7-13.9.4c-1.2.9-1,2.2-1,3.8-.2,9.11-.2,12.61-.3,21.81-.1,2.1,7.1,1.2,8.5.4,1.8-.8.4-2.7,3.8-2.8a1.78,1.78,0,0,1,1.7.8c.2.7-.4,9.3-.3,11,0,.6-1.1.7-1.2.7-4.7-.4-2.5-2.5-4.2-3.6-.9-.7-8.4-2.3-8.4.2,0,1.2-1.2,26.1.7,27.6,2.6,2.1,12.1,2.1,14.1.9,1.8-1.2-.4-3.6,4.4-3.8.1,0,1.2.2,1.2.8-.1,1.2.8,5.1-.1,8.2-.1.5-26.1.1-29.6-.7-.6-.1-1-1-.9-1.6.4-3.8,3.1-1.7,3.9-4.4C593.45,522.62,593.85,473.61,592.55,469.61Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="s-pirates" class="letter" d="M640.05,489.22c8.9,9.4,20.1,19.6,16.1,34.5-1.9,6.8-6.2,12.3-13.5,12.6a13.17,13.17,0,0,1-9.4-3.1c-.3-.3-.9,1.2-1.6,2.2-.4.8-2.7-.1-2.8-.4-.5-.9.4-10.2.8-13.4.1-1.4,3.1-1,3.2-.3a25,25,0,0,0,2.3,6.5c1.4,2.9,4.8,3.5,7,3.5,5.1.1,8.2-3.8,9.2-9.1,2.2-12.1-6.9-20.6-15-29.1-25.91-27.11,1.1-45.91,12.6-34.81.3.3,1-1.2,1.6-2.3.5-.8,2.7.1,2.9.4.4.9-.5,10.2-.8,13.5-.2,1.3-3.2.9-3.3.2a22.58,22.58,0,0,0-2.3-6.4C642.55,453.71,617.15,465.11,640.05,489.22Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="h-have" class="letter" d="M272.55,564.57c0-.09.18-1.06.71-1.06,1.77.09,10.81.35,11.61.53.54.09.89,1,.8,1.42-.35,3.37-2.57,1.5-3.46,4-1,2.83-1.33,11.43-1.42,24.82h16.76c.09-14.72-.18-29.52-.44-30.32-.71-2.39-3.11-.53-3.28-3.9a1.72,1.72,0,0,1,.88-1.51c.8-.18,9.76.36,11.53.27.53,0,.71,1,.71,1.06-.53,5.59-4.34.18-4.52,6.92-.71,17.55-.71,35.82-.8,53.46-.09,2,.09,3.28,1.42,3.81,1.15.45,2.66.53,2.84,3.9,0,.09-.18,1.07-.71,1.07-1.78-.09-10.82-.36-11.62-.53-.53-.09-.88-1-.8-1.51.36-3.37,2.58-1.51,3.37-3.9s1.33-13,1.42-24.56c-5.58-.09-11.17-.09-16.76-.09.09,12.85.36,30.32.54,30.94.71,2.49,3,.62,3.28,4,0,.45-.36,1.33-.89,1.42-.8.18-9.75-.27-11.53-.18-.62,0-.71-1-.71-1.06.54-5.68,4.26-.18,4.53-6.92.71-17.55.71-36.7.79-54.43,0-1.87-.17-3.2-1.41-3.73S272.73,567.94,272.55,564.57Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="a-have" class="letter" d="M335.58,627.61c.27-2.22-1.24-14.9-2.21-21.9-4.26,0-6-.09-10.2-.09-1.42,6.83-2.75,12.41-2.84,14.72,0,1.68,3.28.09,3.37,4.61,0,.18-.17,1.15-.79,1.15-1.78-.09-10.82-.09-11.53-.26-.53-.09-.89-1-.8-1.42.44-3.37,3.28-1.6,4.08-4.08,2.66-8.87,10.11-46.82,11.61-58.43.36-3-2.48-1.68-2.57-5.14,0-.09.18-1.07.8-1.07,1.77.18,9.84-.26,10.64-.08a1.48,1.48,0,0,1,.8,1.5c-.44,3.37-2.66,1.42-2.75,3.9-.09,3.28,6,60,7.8,66.68.71,2.48,3.11.62,3.19,4a1.62,1.62,0,0,1-1,1.5c-.8.09-8.16.18-9.93.18-.27,0-.44-.35-.53-.62C331.68,629.29,335.32,630.18,335.58,627.61Zm-2.83-26.07c-1.42-10.64-1.6-22.52-3.28-32.18-2.49,10.19-3.55,21.37-5.77,32C327.43,601.37,329.11,601.54,332.75,601.54Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="v-have" class="letter" d="M348.44,564.3c-.27,3.37,2.22,15.08,4.79,28.29.35,1.86.88,6,1.24,7.8,1,4.7,2.3,11.17,3.1,14.81.71-3.82,1.51-8.16,2.22-12.68.71-4.26,1.24-9.31,1.95-13.57,1.68-11.26,4.52-29.52,4.34-32.8,0-.71-.53-.71-.71-.8-1.06-.53-2.66-.44-2.92-3.81,0-.09.18-1.07.71-1.07,1.77,0,10.81.09,11.61.18a1.73,1.73,0,0,1,.89,1.51c-.27,3.37-3.1,1.68-3.9,4.16s-3.19,21.2-5.32,34.14c-.09.8-.36,3.81-.53,4.61-1.07,6.47-2.22,11.44-3.11,17.11a86.86,86.86,0,0,0-1.59,9.67c-.09,1.86-.18,6.73-2.75,6.82s-3.19-.71-4.17-5.23c-.09-.53-.8-6.29-2.75-15.69-.71-3.46-1.5-6.65-2.13-10.29-2.83-14.71-5.85-30.14-6.91-33.33-.8-2.4-3.1-.62-3.37-4,0-.53.27-1.33.8-1.42.8-.18,9.84-.27,11.61-.36.62,0,.71,1,.71,1.07C352,564,348.62,562.62,348.44,564.3Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="e-have" class="letter" d="M379.38,569.54c-.8-2.4-3-.54-3.37-3.91,0-.53.36-1.33.89-1.41,3.1-.71,26-.71,26.06-.36.71,2.75-.08,6.38,0,7.54,0,.44-1,.62-1.06.62-4.25-.18-2.22-2.31-3.9-3.37s-10-1.51-12.32.35c-1.07.8-.89,2-.89,3.37-.18,8.07-.18,11.17-.27,19.33-.09,1.86,6.3,1.06,7.54.36,1.6-.71.35-2.4,3.37-2.49a1.59,1.59,0,0,1,1.51.71c.17.62-.36,8.25-.27,9.76,0,.53-1,.62-1.06.62-4.17-.36-2.22-2.22-3.73-3.2-.8-.62-7.45-2-7.45.18,0,1.07-1.06,23.14.63,24.47,2.3,1.86,10.72,1.86,12.5.8,1.59-1.06-.36-3.19,3.9-3.37.09,0,1.06.18,1.06.71-.09,1.06.71,4.52-.09,7.27-.09.44-23.14.09-26.24-.62-.53-.09-.89-.89-.8-1.42.36-3.37,2.75-1.51,3.46-3.9C380.18,616.53,380.53,573.08,379.38,569.54Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="a-anchors" class="letter" d="M445.25,627.61c.27-2.22-1.24-14.9-2.21-21.9-4.26,0-6-.09-10.2-.09-1.42,6.83-2.75,12.41-2.84,14.72,0,1.68,3.28.09,3.37,4.61,0,.18-.18,1.15-.8,1.15-1.77-.09-10.81-.09-11.52-.26-.53-.09-.89-1-.8-1.42.44-3.37,3.28-1.6,4.08-4.08,2.66-8.87,10.11-46.82,11.61-58.43.36-3-2.48-1.68-2.57-5.14,0-.09.18-1.07.8-1.07,1.77.18,9.84-.26,10.64-.08a1.48,1.48,0,0,1,.8,1.5c-.45,3.37-2.66,1.42-2.75,3.9-.09,3.28,6,60,7.8,66.68.71,2.48,3.1.62,3.19,4a1.62,1.62,0,0,1-1,1.5c-.8.09-8.16.18-9.93.18-.27,0-.45-.35-.53-.62C441.35,629.29,445,630.18,445.25,627.61Zm-2.83-26.07c-1.42-10.64-1.6-22.52-3.29-32.18-2.48,10.19-3.54,21.37-5.76,32C437.1,601.37,438.78,601.54,442.42,601.54Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="n-anchors" class="letter" d="M468.48,620.78c0,.09-.18,1.07-.71,1.07-1.77-.09-10.82-.36-11.61-.54a1.46,1.46,0,0,1-.8-1.5c.35-3.37,2.57-1.51,3.46-3.9,2-6,1.33-50.45.88-51.87-.71-2.4-3-.53-3.28-3.9a1.73,1.73,0,0,1,.89-1.51c.44-.09,3,0,5.67.09,1.95.09,2.4,1.95,3.28,4C470,575,475.57,599.5,479.74,614c.8-16.58.27-62-.09-63.12-.71-2.4-3-.54-3.28-3.9a1.72,1.72,0,0,1,.89-1.51c.8-.18,9.75.35,11.52.26.62,0,.71,1,.71,1.07-.53,5.58-4.25.18-4.52,6.91-.71,17.56-.71,49-.8,66.59,0,1.95.18,3.28,1.42,3.81,1.15.36,2.66.44,2.84,3.9,0,.09-.18,1.07-.71,1.07-1.06-.09-4-.18-6.92-.36-1.33,0-2.57-3.37-3-5-3.55-12.15-8.6-36.18-12.94-51.25-.54,15.78-.54,24.74-.63,40.52,0,1.95.18,3.28,1.42,3.81S468.3,617.32,468.48,620.78Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="c-anchors" class="letter" d="M515.12,619.72a36.06,36.06,0,0,0,1-6.12c.18-2.31,4.43-2.84,4.61.44.27,6.56.44,9.49.36,10.73a1.76,1.76,0,0,1-2.31,1.6c-.71-.62-.89-2.75-1.15-2.13-2.84,4.88-6.65,6.56-10.91,6.38-21.37-.79-20.12-73,1.24-73.85a11.08,11.08,0,0,1,8.25,2.84c.27.26.89-1.07,1.42-2,.44-.62,2.39.09,2.57.35.35.8-.44,9-.71,12-.09,1.15-2.75.89-2.93.18a24.12,24.12,0,0,0-1.95-5.68c-1.24-2.66-4.34-3.19-6.29-3.19-15.43-.09-17.38,66.67-.27,65C510.59,625.92,514,623.35,515.12,619.72Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="h-anchors" class="letter" d="M525.75,564.57c0-.09.18-1.06.71-1.06,1.77.09,10.82.35,11.62.53.53.09.88,1,.79,1.42-.35,3.37-2.57,1.5-3.45,4-1,2.83-1.33,11.43-1.42,24.82h16.76c.08-14.72-.18-29.52-.45-30.32-.71-2.39-3.1-.53-3.28-3.9a1.73,1.73,0,0,1,.89-1.51c.8-.18,9.75.36,11.52.27.54,0,.71,1,.71,1.06-.53,5.59-4.34.18-4.52,6.92-.71,17.55-.71,35.82-.8,53.46-.09,2,.09,3.28,1.42,3.81,1.15.45,2.66.53,2.84,3.9,0,.09-.18,1.07-.71,1.07-1.77-.09-10.82-.36-11.61-.53-.54-.09-.89-1-.8-1.51.35-3.37,2.57-1.51,3.37-3.9s1.33-13,1.42-24.56c-5.59-.09-11.18-.09-16.76-.09.09,12.85.35,30.32.53,30.94.71,2.49,3,.62,3.28,4,0,.45-.35,1.33-.89,1.42-.79.18-9.75-.27-11.52-.18-.62,0-.71-1-.71-1.06.53-5.68,4.25-.18,4.52-6.92.71-17.55.71-36.7.8-54.43,0-1.87-.18-3.2-1.42-3.73S525.93,567.94,525.75,564.57Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="o-anchors" class="letter" d="M563.52,615.29c-1.42-11.35-1.42-31.83,0-43.18,2.13-17.65,22.87-17.2,25.53,1.86a146.39,146.39,0,0,1,0,39.45C586.39,632.49,565.65,632.93,563.52,615.29ZM584.36,614c1.5-8.69,1.5-31.75,0-40.52-2.13-12.06-15.17-13.66-16.5-.8-.88,9-.88,33.16,0,42.2C569.19,627.61,582.23,626,584.36,614Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="r-anchors" class="letter" d="M603.06,598.35c-.09,8.78-.18,11.79-.18,20.48,0,1.95.18,3.28,1.42,3.73s2.66.53,2.84,4c0,.09-.18,1.07-.71,1.07-1.77-.09-10.82-.36-11.62-.53a1.49,1.49,0,0,1-.79-1.51c.35-3.37,2.57-1.51,3.46-3.9,2-6,1.32-58.07.88-59.49-.71-2.4-3-.54-3.28-3.91a1.72,1.72,0,0,1,.89-1.5,108.54,108.54,0,0,1,15.69.44c11.44,2.13,11.62,34.85-1.15,39.9a3.9,3.9,0,0,0-.45.09c10.2,7.62,10.11,34,11.89,37.68,1,2,3.81-.09,4.34,4.34,0,.18,0,1.87-.53,1.78-1.78,0-9.67-.27-10.46-.45-.54-.09-.89-1-.89-1.41,0-3.2,3.28-1.6,2.93-3.55s-1.07-36.18-13.92-37.51h-.18C603.15,598.08,603.06,598.17,603.06,598.35Zm6.56-37.41c-3.81-.36-5.76-.45-5.94,4.07-.26,7.45-.35,20.4-.44,28C618.31,597.55,619.29,561.91,609.62,560.94Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
  <path id="s-anchors" class="letter" d="M639.32,586.91c7.89,8.34,17.82,17.38,14.28,30.59-1.69,6-5.5,10.91-12,11.17a11.65,11.65,0,0,1-8.34-2.75c-.26-.26-.79,1.07-1.41,2-.36.71-2.4-.08-2.49-.35-.44-.8.36-9,.71-11.88.09-1.24,2.75-.89,2.84-.27a22,22,0,0,0,2,5.77c1.24,2.57,4.25,3.1,6.2,3.1,4.53.09,7.27-3.37,8.16-8.07,1.95-10.73-6.12-18.26-13.3-25.8-23-24,1-40.69,11.17-30.85.27.26.89-1.07,1.42-2,.45-.71,2.4.09,2.57.35.36.8-.44,9-.71,12-.17,1.15-2.83.8-2.92.18a20.12,20.12,0,0,0-2-5.68C641.54,555.44,619,565.55,639.32,586.91Z" transform="translate(-271.48 -440.61)"/>
</svg>
<style>
body{
  background-color:#000;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 80 80" width="80" height="80"%3E%3Cpath fill="%239C92AC" fill-opacity="0.4" d="M14 16H9v-2h5V9.87a4 4 0 1 1 2 0V14h5v2h-5v15.95A10 10 0 0 0 23.66 27l-3.46-2 8.2-2.2-2.9 5a12 12 0 0 1-21 0l-2.89-5 8.2 2.2-3.47 2A10 10 0 0 0 14 31.95V16zm40 40h-5v-2h5v-4.13a4 4 0 1 1 2 0V54h5v2h-5v15.95A10 10 0 0 0 63.66 67l-3.47-2 8.2-2.2-2.88 5a12 12 0 0 1-21.02 0l-2.88-5 8.2 2.2-3.47 2A10 10 0 0 0 54 71.95V56zm-39 6a2 2 0 1 1 0-4 2 2 0 0 1 0 4zm40-40a2 2 0 1 1 0-4 2 2 0 0 1 0 4zM15 8a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4zm40 40a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4z"%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E');
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#pirates{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -190px;
}
.letter{
  animation: rainbow 5s linear infinite;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #999;
  
}
#r-real{
  animation-delay: -1s;
}
#e-real{
  animation-delay: -.96s;
}
#a-real{
  animation-delay: -.88s;
}
#l-real{
  animation-delay: -.8s;
}
#p-pirates{
  animation-delay: -.64s;
}
#i-pirates{
  animation-delay: -.56s;
}
#r-pirates{
  animation-delay: -.48s;
}
#a-pirates{
  animation-delay: -.4s;
}
#t-pirates{
  animation-delay: -.32s;
}
#e-pirates{
  animation-delay: -.24s;
}
#s-pirates{
  animation-delay: -.16s;
}
#h-have{
  animation-delay: -.88s;
}
#a-have{
  animation-delay: -.8s;
}
#v-have{
  animation-delay: -.72s;
}
#e-have{
  animation-delay: -.64s;
}
#a-anchors{
  animation-delay: -.48s;
}
#n-anchors{
  animation-delay: -.4s;
}
#c-anchors{
  animation-delay: -.32s;
}
#h-anchors{
  animation-delay: -.24s;
}
#o-anchors{
  animation-delay: -.16s;
}
#r-anchors{
  animation-delay: -.08s;
}
#s-anchors{
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes rainbow{
  0%{
    fill: red;
  }
  14%{
    fill: orange;
  }
  28%{
    fill: yellow;
  }
  42%{
    fill: green;
  }
  56%{
    fill: blue;
  }
  70%{
    fill: indigo;
  }
  84%{
    fill: violet;
  }
  100%{
    fill: red;
  }
}
</style>
```

You can also see this code [in JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Coders_Champ/tymuL61j/).
I have seen this code from codepen and implement like this to my website.

Comment: All the letters are paths and there are letters such as lowercase p that are not present in the initial text that you need in the new text so we can't simply change the order of the letters. You could try drawing the missing letters in an SVG editor such as Inkscape.

Comment: @hossein-azizdokht - Can you make the perfect answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change this text because it isn't font. You should design your text and export svg file then open it by a text editor and copy `path data` from `<path d="YOUR PATH DATA">` and replace by current SVG paths. Note that you should not delete previous patch IDs.

[image]